# Get availableAudioDeviceList React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-webrtc

I'm using react-native-incall-manager and React-Native-WebRTC to make audio calls.
I want to know the available audio device list to choose an audio route.
I was only discovered:

Event {"availableAudioDeviceList": "["WIRED_HEADSET","EARPIECE","SPEAKER_PHONE"]", "selectedAudioDevice": "EARPIECE"}

when call

```
      DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('onAudioDeviceChanged', function (data) {
        console.log('Event', data);
      });
```

I just want to know

> availableAudioDeviceList

without listener event. How can I do that?
Thank you.